# How can I implement this card view design in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want the second column of cards to be slightly uneven how can I achieve that.
here is the output that I want:

[image]

Comment: You can use `flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0` plugin for list layout.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that package but I couldn't find this particular solution if you help me defining some values or code that would really help thanks @krisha dhankecha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GridView.builder` like this

```
GridView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
    childAspectRatio: 0.7,
  ),
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: (index % 2) == 0 ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15) : EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: (index % 2) == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: thanks, but can I use cards instead of Containers?

Comment: Then wrap container with card and give it same border radius

Comment: I have edited my answer with card, Please take a look.

Comment: yup that looks good, but if I have to give more padding to the second card then it's just making the size smaller, like if I am changing the value of EdgeInsets.only(top: 15)

Comment: card height depends on `childAspectRatio`, make change in this parameter.

Comment: ya but that will change the size of both the row cards, I want to change the size of the second-row card only thanks

Comment: Then use this condition `(index % 2) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add two columns inside a row:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CardWidget(/*...*/),
          CardWidget(/*...*/),
          CardWidget(/*...*/),
          CardWidget(/*...*/),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          CardWidget(/*...*/),
          CardWidget(/*...*/),
          CardWidget(/*...*/),
          CardWidget(/*...*/),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```